# Type error when running a command

Tags: python

I am getting the following error when running the script below,can anyhelp to identify what the problem is and how to overcome it

CODE:-

```
import sys
import os

def main ():
    to = ''
    with open('caf_gerrits.txt','r') as f :
        for gerrit in f :
            print "Gerrit " + gerrit
            cmd = "ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --format=JSON --current-patch-set --commit-message --files \'%s\'  >> gerrit_output.txt" %(gerrit)
            os.system(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

```
Gerrit 530731

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    cmd = "ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --format=JSON --current-patch-set --commit-message --files \'%s\'  >> gerrit_output.txt" %(gerrit)
  File "test.py", line 10, in main
    to = ''
TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  I don't get this error with CPython 2.7, Pypy 2.2 or Jython 2.7b1.

Comment: I copy/paste and change the cmd, script works. So may be you have some thing did not show here cause the problem. From error message, line 10 is to = '', but we did not see it in your source code. Do we miss some thing here?

Comment: @PasteBT - am using pythong 2.7.3 ,did you create a file caf_gerrits and have some digist like 530731 in it ?

Comment: @user2955256 yes, I do.

Comment: @PasteBT - for some reason I keep seeing this,do you suggest ways to debug or any other approch to resolve this?it probably has to do with the command you are using and I am using

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the escaped single quotes after --files I bet. There is no need to escape them since you used double quotes on the outside.

An alternative solution using 'subprocess' module would look something like the following. Note this was just typed in here, I have not run it. It should be close.

```
def main ():
    to = ''
    ssh_command = ["ssh", "-p", 29418, "review-android.company.com", "gerrit",
                   "query", "--format", "JSON", "--current-patch-set",
                   "--commit-message", "--files", ]

    with open('gerrit_output.txt', 'a') as fp:
        with open('caf_gerrits.txt','r') as f :
            for gerrit in f :
                print "Gerrit " + gerrit
                result = subprocess.check_output(ssh_command + [gerrit, ])
                fp.write(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Check out the docs for the 'subprocess' module, there are plenty of other ways to accomplish this. Any way you choose you get better error handling and better output catching than with a simple 'os.system' call.

Comment: BTW, check out the 'subprocess' module. It has some better features over simply using 'os.system'.

Comment: can you suggest who to use subprocess instead of os.system here?

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
for gerrit in f.readlines():
```

You're trying to iterate using the file descriptor, not the contents of the file itself.

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Comment: @PasteBT - am using python 2.7.3

Comment: @MattDmo - your suggestion did not help

Comment: Using Python 2.7 and 3.x you can loop over the open descriptor.